# ROS2 or ROS alternative or evolution

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS2 will replace ROS or will the two platforms exist?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/282600/ros2-or-ros-alternative-or-evolution/) by [mag.rod](https://answers.ros.org/users/30299/mag.rod/) on ROS Answers with karma: 58 on 2018-02-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It is likely that ROS 1 and ROS 2 will coexist for a very long time. Ultimately ROS 2 is supposed to "replace" ROS 1 but there is currently no plan to discontinue ROS 1.

That being said at least in the ROS 1 base packages not much feature development is being done (especially by OSRF) in favor of focusing the resources on ROS 2.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2018-02-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mag.rod](https://answers.ros.org/users/30299/mag.rod/) on 2018-02-14**:
I think that the change to ROS 2 should be a very substantial change in the base, otherwise it would be logical to remodel ROS 1. This means that the knowledge about ROS 1 will not be useful for ROS 2?

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2018-02-14**:
I don't think this is a valid conclusion. ROS 2 shares a lot of concepts with ROS 1 and those are valuable knowledge across the different versions. For details on the rational why changes were not applied to ROS 1 please see the [design doc](http://design.ros2.org/articles/why_ros2.html).

**Comment by [mag.rod](https://answers.ros.org/users/30299/mag.rod/) on 2018-02-15**:
Ok, Thank you